# Select value range from an array, including duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am given an array `arr` of integers that is sorted in ascending or descending order. If `arr` contains at least two distinct elements, I need to find the longest `arr.last(n)` that has exactly two distinct elements (i.e., with the largest `n`). Otherwise, it should return `arr`. Some examples are:

- `arr = [6, 4, 3, 2, 2]`, then `[3, 2, 2]` is to be returned
- `arr = [6, 4, 3, 3, 2]`, then `[3, 3, 2]` is to be returned
- `arr = [1]`, then `arr` is to be returned.

I would be grateful for suggestions on how to compute the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, but, what do you mean with "two last non-unique integers"?

Comment: Result shows last 3 integers from each array and you say you want 2 last integers? How many do you want?

Comment: @SebastianPalma edited

Comment: For clarity, what would `[1,2,3,4]`, `[1,3,2,3]`, `[]` and `[0]` return?

Comment: @jedi was  edited

Comment: @tadman was edited

Comment: When describing problems like this it's worth describing what happens in edge cases, not ideal cases.

Comment: "please advise on the best and elegant approach to the following task:" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Also, asking for "best" and "elegant" is highly subjective and opinion-based, which is off-topic on [so] as per the [help/dont-ask]. You need to give an exact, precise, objectively measurable, unambiguous definition of what you mean by "best" and "elegant".

Comment: Anton, I trust you don't mind my edit to your question. I believe my understanding of the question is correct in light of your comment on @tadman's answer, but if not, correct my edit or roll back to your original question. I did the edit because you were getting hammered with downvotes and a vote to close (probably because readers found your question unclear), yet it's not a bad question.

Comment: Further to @Jörg's comment about "best" and "elegant", aside from the fact that they are subjective terms, it's not necessary, because many people here always strive to give the most elegant answer they can think of, regardless of whether they are asked to do so.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I seemed to have messed up your previous edit. Sorry. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @sawa Not to worry. Your edit was an improvement, just a minor oversight.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm afraid I'll get old and die sleeping on the paper. You have to admit and deal with the fact of newcomers seeking best and fastest solutions, as this is pure business initiative to produce kilotons of MVP projects hiring literally everyone. Sadly, a top notch professionals like you won't cover everything. If you'll notice a timeline and questions, I ask 1 question once per year. Thank you for your advice, I try to educate, read out and check docs constantly. I was seeking for help at night, being tired and asking for assistance, having few approaches in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly inefficient approach that uses [`take_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-take_while):

```
def last_non_dupe(array, count = 2)
  result = [ ]
  array.reverse.take_while do |n|
    result << n
    result.uniq.length <= count
  end.reverse
end
```

It can be improved on by using a `Set` which is automatically unique:

```
require 'set'

def last_non_dupe(array, count = 2)
  result = Set.new
  array.reverse.take_while do |n|
    result << n
    result.length <= count
  end.reverse
end
```

Where in either case you do:

```
last_non_dupe([6, 4, 3, 2, 2])
# => [3, 2, 2]
```

The `count` argument can be changed as necessary for longer or shorter lists.

Comment: The [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html) library has an incredible amount of tools, so take some time to look through what it offers. There's usually something for every occasion.

Answer (score 3):

```
def last_two_different(arr, count)
  arr.reverse_each.
      lazy.
      chunk(&:itself).
      first(count).
      flat_map(&:last).
      reverse
end

last_two_different [6, 4, 3, 2, 2], 2  #=> [3, 2, 2] 
last_two_different [3, 4, 3, 3, 2], 2  #=> [3, 3, 2]
last_two_different [3, 4, 3, 3, 2], 3  #=> [4, 3, 3, 2] 
last_two_different [3, 4, 3, 3, 2], 4  #=> [3, 4, 3, 3, 2] 
last_two_different [1, 2], 2           #=> [1, 2]
last_two_different [1, 1], 2           #=> [1, 1] 
last_two_different [1], 2              #=> [1] 
last_two_different [], 2               #=> []
```

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = [6, 4, 3, 2, 2]
count = 2

enum0 = arr.reverse_each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [6, 4, 3, 2, 2]:reverse_each>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the values it will generate.

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

First, suppose we wrote the following.

```
enum1 = enum0.chunk(&:itself)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005c29be132b00>:each> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[2, [2, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [4]], [6, [6]]]
```

We want the first `count #=> 2` elements generated by `enum1`, from which we could extract the desired result. That tells us that we want a lazy enumerator.

```
enum2 = enum0.lazy
  #=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator: [6, 4, 3, 2, 2]:reverse_each>> 
enum3 = enum2.chunk(&:itself)
  #=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator:
  #     #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005c29bdf48cb8>:each>>
enum3.to_a
  #=> [[2, [2, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, [4]], [6, [6]]] 

a = enum3.first(count)
  #=> [[2, [2, 2]], [3, [3]]] 
b = a.flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [2, 2, 3] 
b.reverse
  #=> [3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: This is the best I can think of, too.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the efficiency, but here is another way to do it:

```
arr = [6, 4, 3, 2, 2]
uniq = arr.uniq.last(2) # => [3, 2]
arr.select{|e| uniq.include?(e)} # => [3, 2, 2]
```